# which option is better to override product view page?

Tags: magento2, controllers, products-view

Every month we will publish 1 item as hunt item. So customer clicks that product page/opening of product view page we will add some points to customer.

We will store hunt item sku in system config and only one time customer can get points in that calendar month.

What is the simple way to achieve this?

I mean overriding product controller/ observing some event?

**update:**
Following logic is executing for first request only. For subsequent requests its not calling. May be issue with varnish/fpc.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Gigya\Social\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_configScopeConfigInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Gigya\Social\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                                ScopeConfigInterface $configScopeConfigInterface,
                                CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
                                \Gigya\Social\Helper\Data $helper,
                                Context $context,
                                \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $viewHelper,
                                \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
                                PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_configScopeConfigInterface = $configScopeConfigInterface;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $viewHelper, $resultForwardFactory, $resultPageFactory);
    }


    /**
     * Product view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // Get initial data from request
        $categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
        $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');
        $cust_session = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if ($cust_session->isLoggedIn()) {

            $gigyaProduct = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

            if ($gigyaProduct) {
                $huntItem = trim($this->_configScopeConfigInterface->getValue('gigya_gamification/gigya_gamification_conf/huntitem', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE));
                $this->_logger->addInfo('config hunt item:' . $huntItem);
                $this->_logger->addInfo('loaded sku:' . $gigyaProduct->getSku());
                if ($gigyaProduct->getSku() == $huntItem) {
                    $this->_logger->addInfo('its coimg man');
                    $now = new \DateTime('now');
                    $currentMonth = $now->format('m');
                    $year = $now->format("Y");
                    $dateToStore = $currentMonth . '-' . $year;

                    $customerData = $this->customerRepository->getById($cust_session->getId());
                    $storedCurrentMonth = $customerData->getCustomAttribute('gigyahunt');//->getValue();
                    if ($storedCurrentMonth != $dateToStore) {
                        $gigyaAccount = $cust_session->getData('gigyaAccount');
                        $gigyaUid = isset($gigyaAccount['UID']) ? $gigyaAccount['UID'] : $cust_session->getId();
                        $params = [
                            'UID' => $gigyaUid,
                            'action' => 'featuredItem'
                        ];
                        $this->helper->utils->call("gm.notifyAction", $params);
                        $customerData->setCustomAttribute('gigyahunt', $dateToStore);
                        $this->customerRepository->save($customerData);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED)) {
            $product = $this->_initProduct();

            if (!$product) {
                return $this->noProductRedirect();
            }
            if ($specifyOptions) {
                $notice = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
                $this->messageManager->addNotice($notice);
            }
            if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                $this->getResponse()->representJson(
                    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode([
                        'backUrl' => $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl()
                    ])
                );
                return;
            }
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        // Prepare helper and params
        $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

        // Render page
        try {
            $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create(false, ['isIsolated' => true]);
            $this->viewHelper->prepareAndRender($page, $productId, $this, $params);
            return $page;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $this->noProductRedirect();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            $resultForward->forward('noroute');
            return $resultForward;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new action to your module that will add some points to a customer.

Then add JS (as `block` or `widget`) to the product page and make AJAX request to your controller.

Better to use the same hash sign of product id to improve security.